# Checking my laptop battery life by VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In my VB.Net project with framework 2.0, i need to get the current buttery life of laptop or notebook by coding.

It is possible to get the current battery status information?

Comment: Here is readymade code - http://syntaxhelp.com/VB.NET/Retrieve-battery-info

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can Try This Code

```
Dim power As SystemInformation.PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
Dim percent As Single = power.BatteryLifePercent
MsgBox("Percent battery life remaining: " & percent * 100)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Great option for those needing a simple trigger to include in their app, to let users know, "Dude, your battery is getting low."

Thank you for the simple direction!

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [SystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.aspx) class, more specific, the [PowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.powerstatus.aspx) property (which returns an instance of the [PowerStatus class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus.aspx)).

Following code will give you the current battery information:

```
Dim powerstatus As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus

' Gets the current battery charge status.
MessageBox.Show("BatteryChargeStatus : " & powerstatus.BatteryChargeStatus)

' Gets the reported full charge lifetime of the primary battery power source in seconds.
MessageBox.Show("BatteryFullLifetime : " & powerstatus.BatteryFullLifetime)

' Gets the approximate amount of full battery charge remaining.
MessageBox.Show("BatteryLifePercent : " & powerstatus.BatteryLifePercent)

' Gets the approximate number of seconds of battery time remaining.
MessageBox.Show("BatteryLifeRemaining : " & powerstatus.BatteryLifeRemaining)

' Gets the current system power status.
MessageBox.Show("PowerLineStatus : " & powerstatus.PowerLineStatus)
```

Comment: Thank you! Outlined all of the key functions one would need/use to integrate this into their app.